# How can I optimize an access mdb file without changing the structure?

Tags: database, ms-access, jet

Unfortunately I can't change the structure of the database, but how else can I optimise the mdb database?

I've already done the obvious stuff such as [defrag and compacting](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/288631).

What else can I do?

Is SSD the way forward?

Cheers.

Comment: you don't actually say that its slow, or how big it is, or what you are doing with it...., etc...

Comment: What are the problems?  Performance?   Why can't you change the structure of the database?   Have you looked at the indexes?

Comment: What do you mean by the term "optimize"?

Comment: It's slow which is why I want to optimize performance. I can't change the database structure because it's used by a third party application which I cannot change.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not shared among several users, place the MDB not on a network share but on your local PC, to improve performance. And if you're interested only in querying the database, you can load it into a ramdisk.

Comment: Loading into a ramdisk will use up memory that you'd be better off allowing the OS to allocate (both disk caching and paging). Because Jet/ACE is a file-based database, you'll get better performance relying on the OS's disk caching (and Access's internal caching) than you would trying to move things to a ramdisk. Server databases are an entirely different animal, but that's because they aren't file-based like Jet/ACE.

Comment: It is shared database used by multiple users.

Comment: Are you suggesting loading it into a ramdisk on the server? Hmm. I'd be very, very wary of this, since Jet/ACE is really picky about disk access and corrupts easily when all the ducks aren't precisely in a row. The multi-user issue really doesn't have anything to do with it, so far as I can see. Most multi-user slowdowns are related to contention for the LDB file, which won't really be changed by putting the data file in a ramdisk.